# Draw an svg arc using d3 knowing 3 points on the arc

Tags: d3.js

I would like to draw an arc using `d3.js` functions starting at point A via point B and end it at point C.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way using d3 functions like eg. d3.radialLine() or d3.path().arcTo() maybe in combination with other d3 functions without having to code the maths for anything.

Comment: I won't mark it as a duplicate since it's not specific to `d3` but [this is probably what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791951/algorithm-to-find-an-arc-its-center-radius-and-angles-given-3-points)...

Comment: thank you Mark but i would like to know if there is a way using d3 functions like d3.radialLine or d3.path().arcTo() without having to code the maths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a path generator built in d3 to do that – you could grab the one I wrote for [swoopy-drag](https://github.com/1wheel/swoopy-drag/blob/gh-pages/swoopy-drag.js#L143-L173) though:

```js
//convert 3 points to an Arc Path 
function calcCirclePath(start, end, mid) {
  const A = dist(end, mid);
  const B = dist(mid, start);
  const C = dist(start, end);

  const angle = Math.acos((A * A + B * B - C * C) / (2 * A * B));

  //calc radius of circle
  const K = .5 * A * B * Math.sin(angle);
  let r = A * B * C / 4 / K;
  r = Math.round(r * 1000) / 1000;

  //large arc flag
  const laf = +(Math.PI / 2 > angle);

  //sweep flag
  const saf = +((end[0] - start[0]) * (mid[1] - start[1]) - (end[1] - start[1]) * (mid[0] - start[0]) < 0);

  return ['M', start, 'A', r, r, 0, laf, saf, end].join(' ');
}

function dist(a, b) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(a[0] - b[0], 2) +
    Math.pow(a[1] - b[1], 2)
  );
}
```

Comment: What is it `K` and `4` (`A*B*C/4/K`)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Relation_to_the_circumcircle

Comment: How would you go about the same problem but with generating 2 arc segments instead of one?