# Building an arc (an array of segments) at three points

Tags: javascript, geometry

I have the coordinates of three points. I want to build an arc on them 
An arc (non-ideal) consists of segments (let 10 segments).
I need having the coordinates of three points to get an array of arc segments at these points 
How can I do this?
[image: arc at three points]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791951/algorithm-to-find-an-arc-its-center-radius-and-angles-given-3-points

Answer (score 1):

A way, definitely no the shortest way, could be the following.
You have 3 point, thus you can write the circonference equation(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+ax+by+c=0) (for three points pass only a circonference). This is a matter of solving a system of 3 equations in three unknowns. Now given the 2 outermost points,(x1,y1) and (x2,y2), you can calculate the cord length with Pitagora theorem:

cord = √(y2-y1)<sup>2</sup>+(x2-x1)<sup>2</sup>

Now use the theorem of the cord to find the angle in the center that I call *alpha*  thus:

```
sin(alpha/2) = cord/2*radius
```

Having the circonference equation is easy to calculate the radius.
Now that you have `alpha` you can split the angle in 20 parts. For example if `alpha` is 160 you get `Beta`=8

Now you can do:

```
P0 x1,y1
P1 cos(180-8),sin(180-8)
P2 cos(180-16),sin(180-16)
.
.
.
```

and so on until to 160 in my example.
But Attention!  Those above are relative coordinates, relative to the center of the circonference. Called the center (c1,c2) the coordinates will be:

```
P0 x1,y1
P1 c1+cos(180-8),c2+sen(180-8)
P2 c1+cos(180-16),c2+sin(180-16)
.
.
.
```

Comment: No, I need to get exactly an array of lines to create arc wall (for my physical game world). This is not only for render, but for physic too.